# Expected program to print the value of EOF

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf, eof

In the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    for(;scanf("%d",&t);printf("%d",t));

}
```

The program runs as expected when I give general intergers as input. I am working on Windows so when I scanf Cntrl+Z into the argument t, I do not get the value of EOF i.e -1 on the standard output, but the previous argument that was stored in it.
Also when I press Cntrl + D the program terminates, why does Cntrl+D cause scanf to return 0?

And why on scanf Cntrl+C my compiler says: "Process terminated with status -107......" 
I am not understanding why this is happening? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scanf` returns the number of successfully matched formatting specifiers, or `EOF` if the end of input was reached before matching (or failing to match) the first specifier.

When you press Ctrl+Z, `scanf` reaches the end of input and returns EOF (because Ctrl+Z terminates input on Windows). This does not terminate your `for` loop because `EOF` is nonzero, so the previous value of `t` is printed (as `t` was not changed by the call). Note that `t` will not receive the value `EOF` on end-of-input as you seem to expect: `scanf` returns `EOF` as the return value, it does not write it into the pointers you pass to it.

When you press Ctrl+D, it is treated as any other character. Since it is non-numeric, it causes a matching failure for the `%d` specifier and `scanf` returns 0, which terminates the loop.

Comment: And my compiler says "Process terminated with status -107......" when I scanf cntrl+C. Why is that?

Comment: @amiageek Pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break causes a program to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and When ever if you press CTL+Z(CTL+D on linux) will give you zero. otherwise prints 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
        int c;

        while(c=getchar()!=EOF) //here get the character and then compares with the EOF if Not equal 1 will assign to c , if equal 0 will assign to c.
                printf("%d",c);
                printf("%d",c);//when ever we press ctl+Z(ctl+d on linux) then it will print zero remaing all cases this statement wont execute
getchar();
}
```

Comment: Ctrl+D does not cause EOF on Windows.